# console.log is not working when used in a Firefox, Greasemonkey script

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts

My userscript prints some information using `console.log()`.

This works fine in Chrome, but when I install this userscript in Firefox (Greasemonkey), the  web console in Firefox is not displaying anything.

I searched for a solution and some suggested to use `unsafeWindow` but it is also not showing any output. Moreover `unsafeWindow` cannot be used for chrome. I even installed Firebug but it was no use. How can I resolve this?

For example, I tried this userscript in Firefox:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        console
// ==UserScript==
console.log("hello");
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You mean it doesn't work when installed via Greasemonkey, right?
Not long ago, [Greasemonkey broke console.log](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/greasemonkey-users/SGVLuV3H1UM/discussion) (New! [Bug report](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1540)).  Now, to see the results of a plain `console.log()` call from a Greasemonkey, you need to look in *Firefox's* Error console, not Firebug's.

You can see FF's Error console by pressing: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

**However**, you can use `unsafeWindow.console.log()` in both Chrome and Greasemonkey scripts.  Chrome now has limited support for `unsafeWindow`.

If you use `unsafeWindow`, you have access to the full range of [Firebug's logging functions](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) from Greasemonkey. (Firebug must be installed and they still might not work in Chrome userscripts; I haven't tested that way in a while.)

---

In Firefox, **if Firebug is not installed, or it is not active for the page**, then `unsafeWindow.console.log()` calls will display to the New "Web Console" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>).
You need to use the `unsafeWindow` when inside a Greasemonkey script.

Note that Firefox currently supports `console.log()`, `console.info()`, `console.warn()`, and `console.error()` natively -- no Firebug required.

Comment: it is working if i use `unsafeWindow.console.log()` in firebug but how do i get the output in webConsole. is there no way i get the output without using firebug.

Comment: I tried it, it works.  Remember that Firebug must be disabled for the page and you must use `unsafeWindow` unless your script is injected.

Comment: i removed firebug and added unsafeWindow my code now is `// ==UserScript==
// @name        console
// ==UserScript==

unsafeWindow.console.log('hello');` still nothing is displayed in my web Console

Comment: Now i get it in my Web Console under logging only errors is marked so i am not getting output. But does `unsafeWindow` always work in chrome? Thank you and sorry for making silly mistakes.

Comment: Yes, `unsafeWindow` always works in Chrome **for this** (logging purposes).

Comment: I found that the error is not with unsafeWindow.console.log. It is with //@run-at document-start. When i remove this it Firefox is showing output but in chrome i get less tags

Comment: Well then, just use `console.log` without the unsafe.  The only thing is that you will see the output elsewhere on Firefox, but it will be there.

Answer (score 5):

Wait a minute: if the question is about logging in the console with Greasemonkey (I could swear I saw the tag [greasemonkey](/questions/tagged/greasemonkey)), why not use the `GM_log` method?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          GM_log Example
// @namespace     http://www.example.com/
// ==/UserScript==

GM_log("This is an example of GM_log");
```

Or am I missing something?

PS: you can also check for `javascript.options.showInConsole` in about:config. it should be `true`.

Comment: Yes, you can use `GM_log`, but it's not portable or unit testable.  Also, it pretty much sucks compared to the `console` API -- both the native one now supported by most browsers, and the Firebug, extra-sweet, console API.

Answer (score 1):

I found that (testing with Chrome/Tampermonkey) you need:

`window.log("<message goes here>");`, not `unsafeWindow.console.log("<msg>");`,
as `unsafeWindow` and `console` come up as undefined.

Try that, as I'm pretty sure that's the way you're supposed to do it in later versions of browsers, etc.