# Greasemonkey issue with $(document).ready in jQuery

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, loading, document-ready

I cannot figure out why this does not alert me at least once when I visit www.reuters.com. Am I missing something?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test3
// @namespace   test3
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function () {

    var actualHost = window.location.toString();
    var intendedHost = "www.reuters.com";

    alert("Debug 1 - " + actualHost);

    if (actualHost == intendedHost) {
        alert("Debug 2 - " + actualHost);
    }

});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does not work is a really bad description of a problem..

anyway, i see one issue here. try this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test3
// @namespace   test3
// @version     1
// @include     *reuters.com*
// ==/UserScript==

loadDependancies(function () {

    var actualHost = unsafeWindow.location.toString();
    var intendedHost = "www.reuters.com";

    alert("Debug 1 - " + actualHost);


    if (actualHost == intendedHost) {
        alert("Debug 2 - " + actualHost);
    }


});
```

You need to use the `@include` directive that tells GM where the script should run.
You should use `unsafeWindow` to access the window object of that page

you also need to load jquery if it doesnt already exist on the page:

```
DEBUG = true

function addScript(url){
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = url;
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}

function log(msg){
  if(DEBUG){
    unsafeWindow.console && unsafeWindow.console.log(msg);
  }
}

function loadDependancies(boostrapFn) {

  addScript('jquery CDN url goes here..');

  var check = function(){
    log("waiting for dependancies to load: "+ typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery);
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined'){
      window.setTimeout(check, 500);
    }    else {
      jQuery = $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
      boostrapFn();
    }
  }
  check();
}
```

thats your new script. it will load jquery for you to use

Comment: Thank you for input. I mean that none of the alerts trigger and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: you forgot the include directive. take a look at any other working GM script

Comment: Hmm, still not alerting for me.

Comment: ah, you never loaded jquery. let me provide you with a loader

Comment: in my experience i have found that @require directive doesnt work very well.

Answer (score 7):

1. In order to use jQuery, you must load jQuery.
2. `$(document).ready()` is not required in most Greasemonkey scripts as [Greasemonkey fires at the appropriate time](http://wiki.greasespot.net/DOMContentLoaded) by default.

So the simplest version of the script becomes:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     test3
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directive is needed to restore the proper sandbox.

var actualHost = window.location.toString();
var intendedHost = "www.reuters.com";

alert("Debug 1 - " + actualHost);

if (actualHost == intendedHost) {
    alert("Debug 2 - " + actualHost);
}
```

---

Note:

1. Use `@require` whenever possible (which is almost always).

   1. `@require` puts a copy of the script on the local machine, so your script runs faster and is not dependent on an external server for every single run.
   2. `@require` maintains sandbox security/separation, so your script is safe from side-effects or attacks from the target page
   3. `@require` lets your script function even if you've disabled all of the target page's javascript -- a very valuable technique.
   4. `@require` even ports to Chrome, if you use the excellent [Tampermonkey extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo).

   Other, convoluted, methods for adding jQuery have multiple problems:

   1. They are an unnecessary [Security risk](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow).
   2. They make your script unnecessarily dependent on external servers for *every single run*!
   3. They slow your script down.
   4. They make using GM's excellent functions [like GM_xmlhttpRequest() and GM_setValue()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Category:API_Reference), impossible or much more difficult.
   5. They tie your script down to the vagaries of the target page's JS execution.
2. Always give your script appropriate [`@include`, `@exclude`, and/or `@match` directives](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40exclude), so that it will only run on the desired page(s).
3. Consider using [`console.log()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10135917/331508) instead of `alert()`.  It's much less intrusive for debugging.